# Share connection to router from second ethernet

Tags: networking, xubuntu, internet, ethernet

I read all the previous posts but I didn't find anything that fit my needs.
I have a PC with Xubuntu and 2 Ethernet cards.
With a port (`eth1`) I have the Internet connection (static IP address)
I want to share the Internet connection with the second Ethernet (`eth0`) to a router which manages his own network.

I tried configuring the `eth1` with manual IP and the second `eth0` with manual IP too.

I can't use the router to share the connection do you have any idea how to make a working configuration?

Please tell me if you need any extra info, because it's the first time for me in this networking field :(

Comment: This is not enough information. What do you actually want to achieve and what are the networks actually (both IPv4 and non-overlapping address ranges, DHCP or not ...)?

Comment: ok, I'm telling what I have achieved with windows. A wifi connections from the router which connections comes via ethernet from the PC. That's all

Comment: @Nicholas is this http://www.yourownlinux.com/2013/07/how-to-configure-ubuntu-as-router.html what you're looking for?

Comment: @mchid It seems something similar, I want to keep the router external I don't want to have ubuntu as router I don't need that I just want to share the internet connection from my xubuntu to the router and managing the network from there

Comment: If you want your PC to share the connection you either have to make it a bridge or a router. Since you're on static IP i'm guessing that you only have one IP address, if that's the case bridge is out and you have to route through your PC. Why can't you just plug the internet connection directly to the stand alone router?

Comment: If I could I would have plugged the cable directly, but I want to filter my connection using a PC, so that my local network is protected. So at the moment I can only use linux as a router, not using an external router. This is strange that Windows can actually do more thing than linux?!

Answer (score 3):

Thank you everybody.
However I finally found what I needed.
I just needed to configure properly, that's what I was looking for IPTABLES.
If someone else needs to solve a similar problem can take a look in here.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing#Ubuntu_Internet_Gateway_Method_.28iptables.29

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your PC as a firewall it has to stand between Internet and your local network and "route" traffic between them so you need to configure it as a router. Then if you only have one public IP you have to assign private IPs to other hosts and do NAT/masquerade. You can do it on your PC or run a cable to WAN port of the router and let the router take care of it, but then i don't really see the point of PC to "filter" connections. IPs in sub1 need to be configured manually and you can let the router DHCP server to take care of IPs on subnet2

```
---(eth1)Xubuntu(eth0)---sub1---(wan)Router(lan)---sub2---otherPCs
```